# Strip image src from given html

Tags: javascript, image, strip, src

The html contains images path like

```
<img src="/testsite/images/abc.jpg" />
```

I want javascript to convert all images src to be like

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg"/>
```

Simply saying I want to remove any domain/folder name before image/abc.jpg.

How can it be done using javascript?

Comment: means u want all images directly?? without path how it wud b display?

Answer (score 3):

The journey of 1000 miles begins with a single step

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.src = img.src.replace(/^.*(images/[^/]+)$/, "$1");
}
```

Now here's the thing: if you serve up a page with `<img>` elements that have bogus "src" attributes, the browser is going to flail around issuing HTTP "GET" requests to load those URLs.  It'd be somewhat nicer if you could arrange for the server not to send the wrong URLs in the first place.

Comment: Your solution looks great but the problem is that I have given html string, not the HTML document. The string is as follows: 

<P>THIS IS PARAGRAPH&AMP;NBSP;</P>
<IMG ALT="" SRC="/WEBED/IMAGES/BANNERS/BANNER1K.GIF" />....

Comment: @hotcoder well you probably should have made that clear in the original question. If you've got plain HTML, it's still easiest to drop it into a document fragment and then operate on the DOM instead of trying to deal with it as text.  To operate on HTML, it's really necessary to parse it if you want your changes to be accurate. Luckily, the web browser is quite happy to parse HTML for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using replace method
Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).